# Does VisualBasic support WSDL2.0?

Tags: vb.net, wsdl

I'm developing a new SOA system right now, and would like to use WSDL2.0, but I heard some clients are still connect using VisualBasic and WSDL1.1 (mostly from excel sheets and stuff). So I was wondering if VisualBasic also supports WSDL2.0, or if it's all 1.1

I know WSDL2.0 will work with C#,Java,and most other typical application programming languages, and these languages will be used by most of our clients, but I don't want to alienate our VB users, so that's why I'm asking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While VB.NET supports it. I don't think that VB6 clients do when using the now retired SOAP Toolkit 3.0, those clients will either need to do some COM Interop to a component running in the .NET runtime, or upgrade their Excel sheets to Office 2007.

Answer (score 1):

If C# supports it, VB.Net does as well.  They use the exact same set of libraries.  Now, if you have clients connecting from Excel Spreadsheets using VBA that's another story.